# How do I create Pass/Fail/Score Pivot Table without adding formulated columns to the data?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm wondering if anyone can offer a better or alternate solution than what I have for creating a Pass/Fail/Score pivot table.  My solution works visually, but I'm not certain that it is ideal.

**What I have**:  data table with [Pass/Fail] column (contains either "Pass" or "Fail"), and [Score] column (contains a percentage)

**What I want**:  pivot table showing the count of "Pass", the count of "Fail", and the average of the Score.  But I would prefer to not add formulated columns to the data.  And being able to drill into the pivot table for detail is the desired functionality.

**My Solution**:  add 2 formulated columns; [Pass] and [Fail].

[Pass] =IF([@[Pass/Fail]]="Pass",1,0)

[Fail] =IF([@[Pass/Fail]]="Fail",1,0)

Please view this screenshot for further detail

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30zpj.png)

Comment: Countif(range,”pass”) then countif(range,”fail”) and average(score range) which is 3 results in 3 cells. I would also add a check that the total of pass & fail is equal to the number of entries.

Comment: @SolarMike thank you for your response.  But I'm not sure I understand it.  Are you saying to pivot off the countifs?